# How to properly initialize a Future in Flutter Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

so I am trying to build up a list in my provider from a Future Call.

So far, I have the following ChangeNotifier class below:

```
class MainProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<dynamic> _list = <dynamic>[];
  List<dynamic> get list => _list;
  int count = 0;

  MainProvider() {
    initList();
  }

  initList() async {
    var db = new DatabaseHelper();

    addToList(Consumer<MainProvider>(
        builder: (_, provider, __) => Text(provider.count.toString())));

    await db.readFromDatabase(1).then((result) {
      result.forEach((item) {
        ModeItem _modelItem= ModeItem.map(item);

        addToList(_modelItem);
      });
    });
  }

  addToList(Object object) {
    _list.add(object);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  addCount() {
    count += 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

However, this is what happens whenever I use the **list** value:

1. I can confirm that my initList function is executing properly
2. The *initial content* from the **list** value that is available is the
   **Text()** widget that I firstly inserted through the **addToList** function, meaning it appears that there is only one item in the list at this point
3. When I perform Hot Reload, the rest of the contents of the list seems to appear now

Notes:

1. I use the value of **list** in a AnimatedList widget, so I am
   supposed to show the contents of **list**
2. What appears initially is that the content of my **list** value is only one item
3. My **list** value doesn't seem to automatically update during the
   execution of my Future call
4. However, when I try to call the addCount function, it normally
   updates the value of **count** without needing to perform Hot Reload -
   this one seems to function properly
5. It appears that the Future call is not properly updating the
   contents of my **list** value

> My actual concern is that on initial loading, my list value doesn't
>   properly initialize all it's values as intended

Hoping you guys can help me on this one. Thank you.

**UPDATE: Below shows how I use the ChangeNotifierClass above**

```
class ParentProvider extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<MainProvider>(
          create: (context) => MainProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: ParentWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class ParentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mainProvider = Provider.of<MainProvider>(context);

    buildItem(BuildContext context, int index, Animation animation) {
      print('buildItem');

      var _object = mainProvider.list[index];
      var _widget;

      if (_object is Widget) {
        _widget = _object;
      } else if (_object is ModelItem) {
        _widget = Text(_object.unitNumber.toString());
      }

      return SizeTransition(
        key: ValueKey<int>(index),
        axis: Axis.vertical,
        sizeFactor: animation,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            listKey.currentState.removeItem(index,
                (context, animation) => buildItem(context, index, animation),
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300));
            mainProvider.list.removeAt(index);
            mainProvider.addCount();
          },
          child: Card(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
              child: _widget,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          child: mainProvider.list == null
              ? Container()
              : AnimatedList(
                  key: listKey,
                  initialItemCount: mainProvider.list.length,
                  itemBuilder:
                      (BuildContext context, int index, Animation animation) =>
                          buildItem(context, index, animation),
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you using the provider? Where are you adding it via `ChangeNotifierProvider` and where are you fetching it with `Consumer` (or similar to either)?

Comment: Hi @Abion47, thanks for the interest to help. I have a parent ChangeNotifierProvider widget and I access its contents through Provider.of<mainProvider>(context) on a child widget. I access the values via Provider.of under widget build while I only used the Consumer widget as it's child widget is built during initList.

Comment: @Abion47, I have updated my question to show sample code on how I access them. Hoping it helps!

Answer (score 4):

You are retrieving your provider from a `StatelessWidget`. As such, the `ChangeNotifier` can't trigger your widget to rebuild because there is no state to rebuild. You have to either convert `ParentWidget` to be a `StatefulWidget` or you need to get your provider using `Consumer` instead of `Provider.of`:

```dart
class ParentWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<MainProvider>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, MainProvider mainProvider, _) {
        ...
      }
    );
  }
```

---

As an aside, the way you are using provider is to add the `MainProvider` to its provider and then retrieve it from within its immediate child. If this is the only place you are retrieving the `MainProvider`, this makes the provider pattern redundant as you can easily just declare it within `ParentWidget`, or even just get your list of images using a `FutureBuilder`. Using provider is a good step toward proper state management, but also be careful of over-engineering your app.

Comment: Is it better to use Consumer instead of Provider.of for stateless widgets?

Comment: You know, I was already thinking before that I may have been over-engineering my work here and I may have even just gotten away with it before with simpler solutions. I was just looking for efficient methods that I may use before going straight on. That got me really thinking, thanks for that!

Comment: @AverageCoder You have to use `Consumer` in stateless widgets. Otherwise changes in your model aren't going to trigger a rebuild of your UI.

Comment: Just adding that you could also use: context.read<T>() to access and read from a provider too. Also agreeing with everything that @Abion47 said

Comment: @DruhinBala The problem with using `context.read<T>()` is that it is an extension method that wraps `Provider.of<T>(context, listen: false)`, so it won't register the calling widget to listen and rebuild on updates. It's a good shortcut to know about in general, but it wouldn't have helped OP in this case.